# Dont understand jQuery .attr() Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$newUser.addClass(newTweet.user).attr('data-user', newTweet.user).text('@' + newTweet.user + ': ');
var user = $(this).data('user');
```

On line 1 newTweet is an object, but I don't understand the parameter `'data-user`. This isn't referenced in any of the other files, `user`, so is the `'data-'` prefix performing some action? Or does it somehow reference line 2? Or am I completely wrong in both situations, I also don't understand how `.addClass()` method is working in this situation. How does a property of an object get added as a class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr). and for addClass is not a property of an object is the value of that property . `newTweet = { user: 'some-user'; }` so the string `some-user` is added as a class to a HTML element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.attr()` function adds an attribute to an element. You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/.

`data-user` is the name of the attribute added to the element. It doesn't provide any actions, but it's used to store data.

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.
>
> The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.
>
> The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or server-side database queries).
>
> The data-* attributes consist of two parts:
>
> The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"
>   The attribute value can be any string
>
> **Note:** Custom attributes prefixed with "data-" will be completely ignored by the user agent.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp.

Both for the `.attr()` call and `.addClass()` it uses the value of `newTweet.user`, which might be a string.

Comment: Oh I forget to specify, `newTweet.user` is an array. So it's adding it's value to `$newTweet`?

Comment: It stores the `newTweet.user` array in the element `$newUser`. You can access it by using `$newUser.attr('data-user')` which would give back the array. It stores it as an object, so you don't need to do any extra work.

Comment: Then what does `.addClass(newTweet.user)` add to `$newTweet`?

Comment: Calling `.addClass()` with an array doesn't do anything. It only accepts strings, as seen in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/.

Comment: So I could delete `.addClass()` and it wouldnt change anything?

Comment: Huh, that worked, Thanks for the help, wish I could thumb you up more

Comment: So just to clarify cause I'm still a little unsure. `$newTweet.attr('data-user', newTweet.user` Stores the value of `newTweet.user` in `newTweet` under the key `'data-user'`?